# Unable to run simple React native project on IOS fatal error 'config.h' print entry 'CFBundleIndentifier' does not exist

Tags: ios, react-native, bundler

## include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support

```
     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Compile ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/raw_logging.o Sep2018/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/raw_logging.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC Sep2018/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/signalhandler.o /Sep2018/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/signalhandler.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sep2018.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sep2018.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sep2018.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:629:13)
at Promise.then (/Sep2018/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Your question looks quite chaotic, would you please edit it? See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, using this steps solves for me:

Running into the same issue here after upgrading from `0.44`. None of the above solutions or clearing caches did the trick for me. Here's what I did to get things working again:
In the Terminal, navigate to the `react-native/third-party/glog` folder inside `node_modules` (for me, this was *`cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4`*)
Once actively in this folder, run

`sh ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh`

Glog is configured and the required config.h header file is created for Xcode to find

Run your iOS BUILD

Answer (score 1):

- Delete the node_modules
- npm cache verify
- npm install
- XCode Clean
- XCode Run

This helped me with the error.

Comment: I tried the same but still facing  same error  "node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: 'config.h' file not found "